# Comparing strings using jQuery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison

Writing the code i am stuck with one thing. I am loading variable string through jQuery load function and there is where trouble starts. I want my code to check if string loaded through text file had any changes and if that is true make some actions. How do I set my variable as a string to compare it with the one in file? Part of the code

```
var follow, donate;
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {

follow = $('#followerid').load("../Muxy/most_recent_follower.txt");
donate = $('#donatorid').load("../Muxy/most_recent_donator.txt");

}, 100);
```

and then I want to make something like this:

```
someUpdateFunction() {

if($(#'followerid').get("innerHTML") != follow)
// actions (animations, div changes etc.)

}
```

That is probably totally wrong but I wasnt able to find any tips here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.get('../Muxy/most_recent_follower.txt', function (data) {
    var followerid = $('#followerid').html();
    if( followerid == data ){
        // They are the same
    }else{
        // They are not the same
    }
});
```

The `.html()` method will get the HTML inside #followerid. It sounds like that's what you want.

Comment: Yeah the problem strictly is getting out plain text of my #followerid to compare it with the one already loaded in html.

Comment: Show a snippet of the actual HTML and it'll be easy to give you the perfect answer.

Comment: I debugged your fragment of code and it actualy works as intended (i get plain content of my text file and already saved one) and i will start to work with that and see if meet any trouble. Here is my HTML body     <div class="donator animated slideInUp"><div class="unskew" id="donatorid"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="follower animated slideInUp"><div class="unskew" id="followerid"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: I don't see any HTML body, but if it works it works, right?

Comment: Ok, now I see that the contents of followerid is blank. That's easy to test. If there is content in followerid, then just remember that it would be the entire contents, which includes tags and whitespace.

Comment: Problem is that my identity #followerid is now not actually showing in HTML, means that I need to set the value of it somewhere? How to set it without using jQuery.load?

Comment: If you want to set the value in followerid, then `$('#followerid').html('some value');`

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want 'some value' but the content of a text file

Comment: `$('#followerid').load("../Muxy/most_recent_follower.txt");`

Comment: I came up with something like this, in my head it is working but actually not. I want the old text to slide down and new to slide up `$.get('../Muxy/most_recent_follower.txt', function (data) {
    var follow = $('#followerid').html();
    if( follow != data ) {
   $('.follower').set('$', '+animated +slideOutDown').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
    $('#followerid').load("../Muxy/most_recent_follower.txt");
     $('.follower').set('$', '+animated +slideInDown').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
   });
   });
  }
});`

Comment: Yeah, I know you know that's not valid code. You should have a look at jQuery's slideUp and slideDown functions, or for a really custom sliding effect, looking at CSS3 type transitions/animations. Considering the trouble you are having, I'd recommend going over to Youtube an taking a crash course in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery.load function doesn't return the loaded file, it returns the element. Try out this:

```js
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {

   oldFollow = $('#followerid').html();

   $('#followerid').load("../Muxy/most_recent_follower.txt");

   oldDonate = $('#donatorid').html();

   $('#donatorid').load("../Muxy/most_recent_donator.txt");

}, 100);

someUpdateFunction() {
    if($('#followerid').html() !== oldFollow)
    // actions (animations, div changes etc.)

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think you still compare string to an element, at least debugger said so.

Comment: yeah, sorry, forgot something fundamentally, haha...updated it now, hope it works

Comment: I dont see any mistakes here too, but logs of the oldFollow/oldDonator and $('#followerid').innerHTML are both undefined. I think it has something to do with jQuery syntax

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk oohps, it didn't add my second edit...changed it again

Comment: I think problem of this code is the value of `#followerid` is always the same because it is updated every 100ms, isn't it? So as the variable oldFollow changes it has no particular effect because it is already a new one

Comment: It's only always the same, if you don't change it. oldFollow is set before the innerHTML of `#followerid` is updated. So they are definitely different if the file has changed at that moment. But the next 100ms it's of course the same again. Try changing the 100ms to 10000ms and log the values after a change of the file.